# Do you add multiple buildscripts in `app/build.gradle` for manual Android linking in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

In the section adding the gradle plugin for [this React Native component](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup), it tells me to add the following code to `app/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

However, I've added other components that said to add similar code. For example, [this component](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric) says to add this code:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

**What I Want To Know:**

How do you add the code for both of these components into the same project?

Answer (score 1):

You should have one build script and add all the repositories in the *repositories block* and the dependences in the *dependencies block*

it should be like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

for the apply plugins should be in the build.gradle for the app module
add them on the top

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {
 compileSdkVersion 28

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.app.package"
  }
}
```